# Не могу подключиться к lavalink серверу (Connection Failure:: 503)

Tags: python, heroku, discord.py

Хочу сделать музыкального дискорд бота на пайтон, работающего через lavalink. При попытке подключиться с моего компа выдает ошибку:

```
WEBSOCKET | Connection Failure:: 503, message='Invalid response status', url=URL('ws://nock-lavalink-server.herokuapp.com:80')
```

Сервер хостится на heroku через клонированный Github репозиторий (оригинал: https://github.com/F4stZ4p/HLavalink, моя ветка: https://github.com/Nockech/HLavalink, изменял только application.yml), Как могу это исправить? Вот код:

```
from discord.ext import commands
import wavelink
import discord

class MusicCog(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

        if not hasattr(bot, 'wavelink'):
            self.bot.wavelink = wavelink.Client(bot=self.bot)#lavalink-nock-server

        self.bot.loop.create_task(self.start_nodes())

    async def start_nodes(self):
        await self.bot.wait_until_ready()

        await self.bot.wavelink.initiate_node(host = 'nock-lavalink-server.herokuapp.com',
                                              port = 80,
                                              rest_uri = 'http://nock-lavalink-server.herokuapp.com',
                                              password = 'youshallnotpass',
                                              identifier = 'MAIN',
                                              region = 'europe')

    @commands.command()
    async def join(self, ctx, *, channel: discord.VoiceChannel = None):
        if not channel:
            try:
                channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
            except AttributeError:
                raise discord.DiscordException('No channel to join. Please either specify a valid channel or join one.')

        player = self.bot.wavelink.get_player(ctx.guild.id)
        await ctx.send(f'Connecting to **`{channel.name}`**')
        await player.connect(channel.id)

    @commands.command()
    async def play(self, ctx, *, query: str):
        tracks = await self.bot.wavelink.get_tracks(f'ytsearch:{query}')

        if not tracks:
            return await ctx.send('Could not find any songs with that query.')

        player = self.bot.wavelink.get_player(ctx.guild.id)
        if not player.is_connected:
            await ctx.invoke(self.connect_)

        await ctx.send(f'Added {str(tracks[0])} to the queue.')
        await player.play(tracks[0])


def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(MusicCog(bot))
```

Answer (score 0):

Ваш сервер lavalink возвращает ошибку 503. Даже по http протоколу: http://nock-lavalink-server.herokuapp.com
[image: http.cat/503: service unavailable]

[Проверьте логи lavalink сервера.](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging#view-logs)

И я на самом деле не особо вижу зачем вы форкали данный репозиторий, если стандартные значения ровно те же самые
[image: "Connection" раздел README.MD в оригинальном репозитории]

Comment: Подправил свою ошибку, теперь выдает HTTP ERROR 401 при переходе на http://nock-lavalink-server.herokuapp.com, случайно не знаете в чем может быть неполадка?